# Xcode is unable to find symbols for x86_64 architecture

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, linker

I'm new to Objective-C and Xcode.

I'm trying to parse a *YAML* file from my *.mm* file. I decided to use the [yaml-cpp](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/wiki/How-To-Parse-A-Document-(Old-API)) library to accomplish this task.

I downloaded the [source](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/releases/tag/release-0.3.0) and added all the header files to my project. I can include the *yaml.h* header file in my *.mm* file and it successfully builds.

```
#include <yaml-cpp/yaml.h>
...
```

When I try to execute the [sample code](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/wiki/How-To-Parse-A-Document-(Old-API)), with the following statement:

```
std::ifstream yamlReader("vmap3_styleattrs.yaml");
YAML::Parser yamlParser(yamlReader);
```

I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "YAML::Parser::Parser(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
    -[StyleSheetTests testGeoCSSTestAPIPrototype] in StyleSheetTests.o
  "YAML::Parser::~Parser()", referenced from:
    -[StyleSheetTests testGeoCSSTestAPIPrototype] in StyleSheetTests.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The funny thing is, it compiled the first time, but every successive attempt since then, the build has failed with the message above.

I'm wondering whether [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12574420/673730) is related to my situation, although I'm not sure.

I'd appreciate any inputs.

Comment: What did you do with the source files?

Comment: @immibis, I physically copied the source files to my project directory and referenced them in my source code. For e.g. `#include<yaml-cpp/yaml.h>` doesn't throw an error, as I've copied the *yaml.h* header file to the *yaml-cpp* folder in my project directory.

Answer (score -1):

[This screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00jti.png) illustrates the answer outlined below:

I think you can fix through this method.

> Project Setting -> Build Settings -> Apple LLVM 7.0 Language - C++ -> C++ Standard Library
>   And Change `libc++ ( LLVM C++ standard library with C++11 support)` to `libstdc++ (GNU C++ standard library )`

Comment: This change broke my build. Thanks for the try though.